# Repeating appended html with json data included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

This is a bit of a learning exercise for me so please excuse the code I am about to present. I am sure it could be better. In the following code you will see that I have successfully created a variable that is pulling in properly formatted JSON data. I am then, creating a function that appends a block of html. Within that append, I am referencing specific pieces of JSON data to be displayed.

HTML

```
<table id="jobSearchResults" bgcolor="white" style="border: 1px solid #ddd;width:100%;">
  <tbody>  
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

Javascript

```
var json = (function () {
            var json = null;
            $.ajax({
                'async': false,
                'global': false,
                'url': "../data/jobSearchResults.json",
                'dataType': "json",
                'success': function (data) {
                    json = data;
                }
            });
            return json;
        })(); 

$(jobSearchResults).each(function(index, element){
  $('#jobSearchResults').append('<tr><th><div style="background-color:#ddd;height:55px;width:80px;"><img src="" style="height:55px;width:80px;"></div></th><td><h4 style="margin-top: 0;margin-bottom: 2px;font-size: 16px;"> '+json[0].job_header+' </h4> '+json[0].specialty_name+', '+json[0].facility_name+' </td><td><h4 style="margin-top: 0;margin-bottom: 2px;font-size: 16px;"> '+json[0].city+',  '+json[0].state_name+' </h4> United States </td><td class="text-right"></td></tr>');       
});
```

Now, I need to complicate matters by making that table row repeat X number of times and have the JSON record number increment with each new row. In this case, I am both interested in how to take what I have written and expand on it to include this new functionality and I am also interested in what a more concise way to approach this problem would have been had I written this more efficiently.

Comment: Here is my current fiddle for this with the JSON data: https://jsfiddle.net/epearson001/50692r93/1/

Comment: It seems that your code is working. Within your `each` loop, you can use `index` to reference the current iteration's index, or `element` to reference the current value directly. For example: `json[index].job_header` or `element.job_header`. See examples at [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). Is that what you're asking?

Comment: The idea here is that if I want to expand this to 50 rows of data, I don't want to do that in the append function manually. I certainly could but that would be silly. Your recommendation seems like it might be in the right direction. I will look into this option further.

Comment: I just noticed that you're iterating over `jobSearchResults` rather than the `json` variable. But maybe that's just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function for jQuery's [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) is passed two values. They represent the index and value of the current iteration, respectively. You can use either of these to reference your original JSON data and output each row accordingly.

> The $.each() function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an object or an array. In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time.
>
> ```
> $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
>   alert( key + ": " + value );
> });
> ```

In my example below, I'm iterating over the `json` variable, which contains the JSON data returned from your AJAX call. In this context, you could use the index to reference the current iteration (e.g. `json[index].job_header`) or use the value directly (e.g. `job.job_header`).

```js
function displayData(json) {
  
  var $resultDisplay = jQuery('#jobSearchResults tbody');
  
  if (!json) {        
    // variable is false. there was an ajax error.
    $resultDisplay.html('<tr><td>There was an error.</td></tr>');        
  } else if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(json)) {        
    // variable is an empty object. no records were returned.
    $resultDisplay.html('<tr><td>No data to display.</td></tr>');        
  } else {
    
    // display the returned records.
    $resultDisplay.empty();
    jQuery.each(json, function(index, job) {
      $resultDisplay.append('<tr>' +
        '<td><div class="row-img"><img src="" alt=""></div></td>' +
        '<td><h4>' + job.job_header + '</h4>' + job.specialty_name + ', ' + job.facility_name + '</td>' +
        '<td><h4>' + job.city + ',  ' + job.state_name + ' </h4>United States</td>' +
        '</tr>');
    });
    
  }
  
}

jQuery.ajax({
    'url': "https://epearson001.github.io/prototype-web-application/assets/data/jobSearchResults.json",
    'dataType': "json"
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    displayData(data);
  })
  .fail(function() {
    displayData(false);
  });
```

```css
#jobSearchResults {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
div.row-img {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 55px;
  width: 80px;
}
div.row-img img {
  height: 55px;
  width: 80px;
}
h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="jobSearchResults">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Loading data...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

### Edit

I also notice that you're setting `async` to false in your AJAX call. This defeats the asynchronous functionality of AJAX and, unless there's a particular reason to do so, I advise against it. I've restructured my example to use a callback function, so that data will be displayed after it is returned from your asynchronous AJAX call. I also added a bit of error handling. I acknowledge that this might not be appropriate for your particular context, but I thought I'd offer the idea.

Comment: Excellent. This clears up a few core concepts that I was misunderstanding.

Comment: Your edit did a great job of expanding my scope of thought to fallback methods and such. I need to do a better job of incorporating them in from the start. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure. It's always fun to play with a live JSON feed :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

The answer given definitely shows the right way to do what you're asking.  But I would've approached this differently if you are controlling the server as well.  Instead of sending JSON data back, I'd send formatted HTML back and use:

```
$('#jobSearchResults tbody').load('../data/jobSearchResults/')
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I will definitely consider trying this method.

Comment: Not sure what your back end is in, but templating languages like jinja for Python are built to create dynamic HTML.  I believe you should let them do what they're good at. Let javascript do what it's good at, and let the server language do what it's good at. 

You will have a much easier time managing your HTML if it's done this way as well.

Comment: In the rare instances I'm forced to manipulate HTML with javascript extensively like this, I will usually create a blank version of the table row, and hide it somewhere on the page.  Then I'll use var new_row = $('#hidden_row_template').clone() and the template row will have tags like <span class="value1"></span> in them and I'll sub values in like new_row.find('.value1').text(json.value1) then new_row.appendTo('#jobSearchResults tbody)